# How to sum two values in array together in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

I have a list of available stock that I get Via Api

the list looks like this:

```
{
  "Total": 4,
  "Page": 1,
  "ProductAvailabilityList": [
    {
      "ID": "53350e22-0a89-4bdd-b11c-90bb3315dbe1",
      "SKU": "test product 1",
      "Name": "Test product 1",
      "Barcode": null,
      "Location": "Main Warehouse",
      "Bin": null,
      "Batch": null,
      "ExpiryDate": null,
      "OnHand": 0,
      "Allocated": 1,
      "Available": 1,
      "OnOrder": 0,
      "StockOnHand": 0
    },
    {
      "ID": "92a8c8fd-318e-455a-945c-8c5f588c055e",
      "SKU": "test product 2",
      "Name": "Test product 2",
      "Barcode": null,
      "Location": "Main Warehouse",
      "Bin": null,
      "Batch": null,
      "ExpiryDate": null,
      "OnHand": 0,
      "Allocated": 1,
      "Available": 1,
      "OnOrder": 0,
      "StockOnHand": 0
    },
    {
      "ID": "a2bd1fc5-f52c-4005-89a7-b9fdb4f180e1",
      "SKU": "test product 3",
      "Name": "Test product 3",
      "Barcode": null,
      "Location": "Main Warehouse",
      "Bin": null,
      "Batch": null,
      "ExpiryDate": null,
      "OnHand": 0,
      "Allocated": 1,
      "Available": 1,
      "OnOrder": 0,
      "StockOnHand": 0
    },
    {
      "ID": "3e14fcbc-6e80-4c36-8c2c-36e29f79e192",
      "SKU": "test product 4",
      "Name": "Test product 4",
      "Barcode": null,
      "Location": "Main Warehouse",
      "Bin": null,
      "Batch": null,
      "ExpiryDate": null,
      "OnHand": 0,
      "Allocated": 5,
      "Available": 2,
      "OnOrder": 0,
      "StockOnHand": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to sum together the total of stock on hand for a specific item the problem that I am having is that if there is an item with 2 different batch nr it creates two different array groups

Comment: Do you want total to be returned as a new value or to override 'total' value in the beginning of the array?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that your question is missing some information (like expected result), but nevertheless you can use the following code to get the total "stock on hand" for a **specific** item:

```
let items= {
  "Total": 4,
  "Page": 1,
  "ProductAvailabilityList": [
    {
      "ID": "a2bd1fc5-f52c-4005-89a7-b9fdb4f180e1",
      "SKU": "test product 1",
      "Name": "Test product 1",
      "Barcode": null,
      "Location": "Main Warehouse",
      "Bin": null,
      "Batch": null,
      "ExpiryDate": null,
      "OnHand": 0,
      "Allocated": 1,
      "Available": 1,
      "OnOrder": 0,
      "StockOnHand": 2
    },
    {
      "ID": "92a8c8fd-318e-455a-945c-8c5f588c055e",
      "SKU": "test product 2",
      "Name": "Test product 2",
      "Barcode": null,
      "Location": "Main Warehouse",
      "Bin": null,
      "Batch": null,
      "ExpiryDate": null,
      "OnHand": 0,
      "Allocated": 1,
      "Available": 1,
      "OnOrder": 0,
      "StockOnHand": 0
    },
    {
      "ID": "a2bd1fc5-f52c-4005-89a7-b9fdb4f180e1",
      "SKU": "test product 3",
      "Name": "Test product 3",
      "Barcode": null,
      "Location": "Main Warehouse",
      "Bin": null,
      "Batch": null,
      "ExpiryDate": null,
      "OnHand": 0,
      "Allocated": 1,
      "Available": 1,
      "OnOrder": 0,
      "StockOnHand": 5
    },
    {
      "ID": "3e14fcbc-6e80-4c36-8c2c-36e29f79e192",
      "SKU": "test product 4",
      "Name": "Test product 4",
      "Barcode": null,
      "Location": "Main Warehouse",
      "Bin": null,
      "Batch": null,
      "ExpiryDate": null,
      "OnHand": 0,
      "Allocated": 5,
      "Available": 2,
      "OnOrder": 0,
      "StockOnHand": 0
    }
  ]
};

function stockSum(list: typeof items.ProductAvailabilityList, productId: string): number {
  return list.filter(item => item.ID === productId).reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.StockOnHand, 0);
}

console.log(stockSum(items.ProductAvailabilityList, "a2bd1fc5-f52c-4005-89a7-b9fdb4f180e1"))
// this logs the number 7
```